# lots of 0kb file in cpanel hosted public_html dir

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting, public-html

i'm supposed to take over an old laravel project which is hosted (and presumably previously managed) using cpanel. i can see a lots of 0kb files in the public_html dir. for ex:

- 55ojAH
- FnhBRE
- ioZ5MP
- myApp_dNWuzR
- myApp_TdfPsE

etc. i'm guessing those are temp files but looking for an explanation, by which process those 6 digits files were created.

Comment: How should anybody else know that? Maybe that website got hacked? Maybe it uses such files as caching files?

Comment: You need to consult the old owners/developers from whom you have taken over the project.

Comment: @nicoHaase understood, i'd consider the possibility of hacking but not sure if that's the case then 0kb (no content) makes any sense, i was hoping the 6 character pattern might indicate something, my guess is some process created it but got interrupted

Comment: A hacking attempt could produce such files to check whether creating files through code injection is possible

Comment: @VishwaRatna duly noted, of course the owner isn't much knowledgeable about what's going on, maybe if they can get hold of the previous dev, but considering it was probably previously managed using cpanel interface and there's a lot of junk there, i'm guessing maybe s/he wasn't either aware or didn't bother about the extra files